# How to add an extra context in a Class Based View (ListView)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to add another Context in a ListView so that it can be used in the same template but it is not working and it gets an error for

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['score/user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']
```

The 1st applied context is called Items model  from a Core app, the 2nd context that I want to apply is the post model from score app

Here is the Views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            context['posts'] = None
        return context
```

Here is the models for Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the template which return the

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['score/user/(?P[^/]+)$']

```
{% if posts %}
 <a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
 Check my posts</button>
 </a>

{% else %}
Show Nothing
{% endif %}
```

Here is the template which returns no errors but the if statement doesn't work

instead of using

{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}

I used

{% url 'score:user-posts' item.designer.username %}

```
{% if posts %}
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
Check my posts</button>
</a>

{% else %}
Show Nothing
{% endif %}
```

here is the URLs.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

here is the score urls.py

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show your urls.py( + directory structure of your project)
i am not sure, but looks like you get wrong template file

But in your code you can change:

```
try:
    context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    context['posts'] = None
```

you don't need try ... except... here. If you have empty table,  Post.objects.all() will return empty queryset and you will never get your Exception

i think you need to add line in your urls.py

```
path('score/user/<slug:username>/', HomeView.as_view(), name="user-detail")
```

and then in your template you can use

```
{% url 'user-detail' item.designer.username %}
```

Comment: I added the URLs.py, I didn't fully understand what you meant by instead of using the try and except. What should I replace it with ?

Comment: just leave one string `context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()`

Comment: Ahh ok thanks but still I'm getting no reverse  `Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['score/user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: i modified my answer

Comment: Even if it is already available in the Score urls.py `path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),` ?  I will add the score urls in the question

Comment: looks like you added only part of your urls.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216609/discussion-between-ahmed-khairy-and-maslov-andrey).